# Java database insertion fails

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

My program should get data from xml files and put them in the db.

I use phpmyadmin mysql database.

I succeeded getting data from the XML, but when I try to put it in database it fails.

DBInput.java // JFrame with a button. when button is pressed program is supposed to put data in database.

```
package jSpyDroidEclipse;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.spi.CurrencyNameProvider;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class DBInput extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private File xmlFile;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */


public String strStr(String haystack, String needle) {
      if(haystack==null || needle==null) return null; 
      int hLength=haystack.length(); 
      int nLength=needle.length(); 
      if(hLength<nLength) return null; 
      if(nLength==0) return haystack;
      for(int i=0; i<=hLength-nLength; i++)
      {
        if(haystack.charAt(i)==needle.charAt(0))
        {
          int j=0; 
          for(; j<nLength; j++)
          {
            if(haystack.charAt(i+j)!=needle.charAt(j))
            {
              break; 
            }
          }
          if(j==nLength) return haystack.substring(i) ; 
        }  
      }
      return null; 
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                DBInput frame = new DBInput();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public DBInput() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JButton b_browse = new JButton("Browse");
    b_browse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

             fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("user.home"));
                fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Select the XML file");
                fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
                if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(b_browse) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    xmlFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();


                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
                    try {
                        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(xmlFile));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    String currentLine = null;
                    try {
                        currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    StringBuilder xmlCode = new StringBuilder();
                    xmlCode.append(currentLine);

                    if((currentLine!=null) && !currentLine.equals(""))
                    {
                        try {
                            while((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
                            {
                                xmlCode.append(currentLine);
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }


                    String sXMLCode = xmlCode.toString();

                    DBConnect connect = new DBConnect();
                    while(sXMLCode!=null)
                    {

                        String adv_name = XMLParser.getItem(new String(sXMLCode), XMLParser._TAG_ADV_NAME);
                        String category = XMLParser.getItem(new String(sXMLCode), XMLParser._TAG_CATEGORY);
                        String curency = XMLParser.getItem(new String(sXMLCode), XMLParser._TAG_CURENCY);
                        String free_shiping = XMLParser.getItem(new String(sXMLCode), XMLParser._TAG_FREE_SHIPPING);
                        String gift = XMLParser.getItem(new String(sXMLCode), XMLParser._TAG_GIFT_INCLUDED);
                        String manufacturer = XMLParser.getItem(new String(sXMLCode), XMLParser._TAG_MANUFACTURER);
                        String price_no_vat = XMLParser.getItem(new String(sXMLCode), XMLParser._TAG_PRICE_NO_VAT);
                        String price_vat = XMLParser.getItem(new String(sXMLCode), XMLParser._TAG_PRICE_VAT);
                        String PRODUCT_AFF_LINK = XMLParser.getItem(new String(sXMLCode), XMLParser._TAG_PRODUCT_AFF_LINK);
                        String PRODUCT_CODE = XMLParser.getItem(new String(sXMLCode), XMLParser._TAG_PRODUCT_CODE);
                        String PRODUCT_DESC = XMLParser.getItem(new String(sXMLCode), XMLParser._TAG_PRODUCT_DESC);
                        String PRODUCT_NAME = XMLParser.getItem(new String(sXMLCode), XMLParser._TAG_PRODUCT_NAME);
                        String PRODUCT_PIC = XMLParser.getItem(new String(sXMLCode), XMLParser._TAG_PRODUCT_PIC);


                        String query = "INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(product_code, adv_name, category, manufacturer, gift_included, product_name, product_desc, product_aff_link, product_pic, price_no_vat, price_vat, free_shipping) VALUES("+
                                                            PRODUCT_CODE + "," + adv_name + "," + category + "," + manufacturer + "," + gift + "," + PRODUCT_NAME + "," + PRODUCT_DESC + "," + PRODUCT_AFF_LINK + "," + PRODUCT_PIC + "," + price_no_vat + "," + price_vat + "," + free_shiping + ");";

                        connect.insertData(query);                      


                        //shifting to next product
                        String code = xmlCode.toString();
                        sXMLCode = strStr(sXMLCode.substring(1), XMLParser._TAG_PRODUCT);
                        //connect.disconnect();
                        //connect = null;
                    }
                }
        }
    });
    b_browse.setBounds(164, 103, 97, 25);
    contentPane.add(b_browse);
    }
}
```

DBConnect.java

```
package jSpyDroidEclipse;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;

public class DBConnect {

private Connection connection;
private Statement statement;
private ResultSet resultSet;
private PreparedStatement preparedStatement;

public DBConnect()
{
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        //TODO: hardcoded
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/admin", "root", "");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


// it runs the query and returns the dataset
// query is supposed to be a select statement
// TODO: CHECK query to be a select statement
public ResultSet selectData(String query)
{
    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        statement.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        resultSet.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return resultSet;
}



//TODO: set type ResultSet and return inserted data
public void insertData(String query)
{
    try {
        preparedStatement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(query);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        preparedStatement.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    try {
        preparedStatement.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void updateData(String query)
{

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
     DBConnect connect = new DBConnect();
}

public void disconnect()
{
    try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        preparedStatement.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        resultSet.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        statement.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    connection = null;
    preparedStatement = null;
    resultSet = null;
    statement = null;
 }
}
```

I also tested insertion method without that while loop and it works.

Error message:

> java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964‌​)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897‌​)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886‌​)

Comment: have you tried debugging your application? Check your query and see if the number of parameters are matching or not. Check if none of the parameters are getting `null` value. If you are able to insert value without while loop, then check whether all parameters are present throughout the while loop.

Comment: Please post your complete error stack

Comment: @Jeyaprakash it's very long and there is a post limit

Comment: @Gaurang Despande Paramaeters are not null for sure. I read it from a file and i double checked what's inside. I also checked the number of parameters. "No value specified for paramater 1"... I really don't know what that is supposed to mean.

Comment: Ok can you add line nuber shown by the stacktrace because your code is so long

Comment: connect.insertData(query);                 // this line is signaled by stacktrace

Comment: This also several times: at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Comment: Could it be missing apostrophes?  Try outputting the actual SQL first to see what it looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First : You are using `PrepapredStatement` with a wrong way,
2. Second: i assume that type values like `PRODUCT_CODE`, `adv_name` is String, and String should be between two quotes `'value'`

To solve your problem, you can :

1. Instead of `public void insertData(String query)` you can create two method, one return the prepared statement, the second to close the the statement
2. for each object create a method which take your Object, call prepapred statement, execute the statement, and close the statement in the end

Here is a simple example :

```
String query = "INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(product_code, adv_name, category, manufacturer, "
        + "gift_included, product_name, product_desc, product_aff_link, "
        + "product_pic, price_no_vat, price_vat, free_shipping) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ....)";
try (PreparedStatement pstm = getPreparedStatement(query)) {
    pstm.setString(1, PRODUCT_CODE);
    pstm.setString(2, adv_name);
    pstm.setString(3, category);
    ...
    pstm.execute();
    closeStatement(pstm);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to be using apostrophes.  At the least it should be something like:-

```
   String query = "INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(product_code, adv_name, category, manufacturer, gift_included, product_name, product_desc, product_aff_link, product_pic, price_no_vat, price_vat, free_shipping) 
   VALUES('"+ PRODUCT_CODE + "','" + adv_name + "', [etc]
```

..although this can leave you open to SQL injection attacks, so I would use parameters.

Answer (score 2):

For sure in below line:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(product_code, adv_name, category, manufacturer, gift_included, product_name, product_desc, product_aff_link, product_pic, price_no_vat, price_vat, free_shipping) VALUES("+
                                                            PRODUCT_CODE + "," + adv_name + "," + category + "," + manufacturer + "," + gift + "," + PRODUCT_NAME + "," + PRODUCT_DESC + "," + PRODUCT_AFF_LINK + "," + PRODUCT_PIC + "," + price_no_vat + "," + price_vat + "," + free_shiping + ");";
```

You need to change your code like below:

```
'"+PRODUCT_CODE+"',
```

And other variables also.

You can feel this(String concatenation) is a terible way to query. You need to use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). This will also avoid [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).